# Formula Wizard Result Doesn't Match Displayed Cell Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a simple formula that is displaying correctly in every cell above and below one problem cell. It is showing as blank (and if you try to do a sum, it is truly blank), but the function argument displays the result as 3,313.

- Auto-calculations are on.
- If I add this cell to a cell that's equal to 10, the result is 10
- The formula is:`=IF(SUM(X25:X106<1),"",X25)`

I suspect the issue is not with the formula, as it works everywhere else.

[image: Formula Wizard - which SHOULD be the value]

[image: Displayed Value of Nothing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `)` wrong:

```
=IF(SUM(X25:X106)<1,"",X25)
```

Comment: Unfortunately isolating the sum is not working, and this formula works in other cells without issue. Strangely enough, if I flip the greater than sign, it works. The formula wizard shows the 3,313 total for both greater than and less than.

Comment: Update: Thank you! After isolating the sum in exactly the same manner, it worked (but only after the 10th time or so). If anyone understands why my first formula wasn't working in one instance out of 80+, I'm very interested! I'm going to be losing sleep over this!

Comment: @AriaDewes Well, the original formula was wrong. The result of `X25:X106<1` is an array with TRUE/FALSE values, and the sum of that is always zero, unless you put `--` before, which converts the TRUE to 1, so you would actually get the number of TRUE values. But I assume this is not at all what you wanted to do. The fact that it worked (or gave a predicted result) for other cells does not mean that the formula was correct !

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the sum function could be an array. I'll write my formulas more neatly in the future- your explanation really helped!